# How to add geometry column using pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin

I'm using a database created in the PostgreSQL. In its schema there are two tables and in one of them I want to add a `geometry` column.

The problem is that I created the postgis Extension (`CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`) for the database, but I'm not able to add this data type (geometry) column using pgAdmin.

Comment: Show us the statement you are running to add the columns and the error message you get ([Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35384346/edit) your question). Did you commit the `create extension`?  What does `select extname from pg_extension` show you? Is PostGIS listed there?

Comment: I can alter the table using the command line where i can add the geometry column; I have no error message in in the pgAdmin GUI but in the data-type entry I cannot find 'geometry'

Comment: Then why don't you simply use an `alter table`?

Comment: Sure but I want to know the reason why it doesn't work with the GUI :)

Comment: It should work in PgAdmin too...Do you connect to the right database? try to disconnect and connect again.

Comment: I had the same trouble. My pgadmin version is 4.18. I created db and called CREATE EXTENSION postgis; After these actions, I have found the geometry type in GIU.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this with pgAdmin's "New Column..." dialog, if you can't find `geometry`, then you might be able to find `public.geometry` instead (if PostGIS was installed there, which is normal).

However, I advise against using pgAdmin for creating geometry columns, as it does not understand typmods used to define the geometry type and SRID.

The best way is using [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) to directly manipulate the table, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE locations ADD COLUMN geom geometry(PointZ,4326);
```

to add a `geom` column of XYZ points (long, lat, alt).