# How to add a centroid column from the geom column using postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have the following table (table_example) in a database on postgres:

```
      id         geom              class        area_total                 
     1255      65f56f6565...       type_1         1244589
     1256      65f56f6566...       type_2         2542542
```

I need to create a new column that, from the geometry of the polygon, receives the value of the centroid of the polygon.

Based on this link ([How to add geometry column using pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384346/how-to-add-geometry-column-using-pgadmin)) I tried to do the desired operation as follows:

```
         -- The idea is to first create a column that is of type geometry
         ALTER TABLE table_example 
         ADD COLUMN column_geom_centroid geometry(geom);

        -- And then assign the centroid value to the column
        UPDATE table_example
        SET column_geom_centroid = ST_Centroid(geom)
```

However, when I run the first command (ALTER...) the following error appears:

```
        ERROR:  Invalid geometry type modifier: geom
        LINE 2: ADD COLUMN column_geom_centroid geometry(geom);
                                     ^
        SQL state: 22023
        Character: 70
```

Answer (score 0):

it`s better to use postgis function `AddGeometryColumn`, for creating geometries columns
https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html

Example

`SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('my_schema','my_spatial_table','geom_c',4326,'POINT',2, false);`